# Multithreading with dispatch_async with return value

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

The problem I am having is that I need to return the `region` value inside the dispatch_async code which in turn should return the region for the outer function. The dispatch_async code within the function is below:

```
dispatch_async(regionQ, ^{
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoInformationURL];
    NSDictionary *photoPlaceDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                         options:0
                                                                           error:NULL];
    NSString *regionName = [FlickrFetcher extractRegionNameFromPlaceInformation:photoPlaceDictionary];
    region = [self createRegionWithName:regionName withContext:context];
});
```

There is another catch to this. The function `[self createRegionWithName:regionName withContext:context]` is also a function that contains a dispatch_async.

I thought of trying to put return statements at the end of the blocks, but that would result in a giant mess of nested calls to various helper functions to determine the completion of my queue. I need a better way to do this.

Comment: You can use a dispatch_semaphore to await the value.  Or just dispatch_async yourself back onto the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use messaging! You should send notification at the end off `dispatch_async` and handle that notification. Just google about it.